# Crear una lista clave valor en Java

Tags: java, android

Cómo se crea una lista en `Java Android`del tipo *diccionario* es decir que se pueda almacenar contenido `clave:valor`,la clave y su valor sean `String`.

**Update 1**

Tengo realizado lo siguiente:

```
Map<String, String> listParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Para agregar parámetros:

```
listParams.put("offset","3");
listParams.put("items","50");
listParams.put("sort","title,asc");
```

Para recorrer todos los elementos

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : listParams) {
    String.format("llave: %s, valor: %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Me da el siguiente error

> Test.java:37: error: for-each not applicable to expression type
>   for(Map.Entry entry : listParams) {
>                                          ^   required: array or java.lang.Iterable   found:    Map 1 error

Comment: tengo curiosidad para que usarías en tu aplicación los datos de esta forma y no en un listado de objects?

Comment: Buenas @Elenasys estoy pensando en crear una classe para almacenar los parámetros de una conexión URL cómo por ejemplo ofsset=4   items=50    sort=asc,title, mientras descubro Java veo que hay Clases Madre.

Comment: Yo en mis proyectos utilizo `Map`, y si revisas otros proyectos también utilizan `Map` para pasar dichos parámetros.

Comment: Disculpa, he corregido el código que presento en mi respuesta.

Comment: @Webserveis Hola amigo, ok precisamente podrías crear una clase "Padre" que tenga todos los campos y las que extiendan de esta, podrán usar algunos de estos valores o incluso implementar sus propios campos. Si no simplemente un HashMap.

Comment: Otra forma es usar SpaceArray en Android https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560629/sparsearray-vs-hashmap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utiliza la clase [`Pair`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html) en su lugar:

```
List<Pair<String, String>> listParams = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
```

O en su defecto y más práctico, utiliza un `Map` directamente, puesto que ya es una colección de pares de valores:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

En caso de utilizar `Map`, puedes navegar todos los valores allí utilizando el siguiente código:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(
        String.format("llave: %s, valor: %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())
    );
}
```

Comment: Pero la lista map como se agrega valores con setKey y setValue? o hay una forma más directa de insertar datos

Comment: @Webserveis no estoy colocando una lista de mapas, en ninguna parte de mi ejemplo. Te propongo dos formas, 1) utilizando `List<Pair>`, 2) utilizando `Map`. Si escoges el mapa, deberás utilizar `Map#put`.

Comment: Gracias ya me funciona